How to synchronize threads in PyQt?
I want to accomplish the following in pyQt:
Run task 1 and task 2, in separate threads (not in the main thread), as parallel as possible. Only when both threads are finished, trigger running task 1 and task 2 in parallel again.
Task 1 and task 2 are serial port queries (read + write) to/from 2 different devices using the pyserial library.
Whenever I try to implement this by starting both threads, they seem to start at the same time, but I can not synchronize restarting threads when they finish execution, by using signals/slots.
A Button click triggers the "start' method.
    def start(self):
        self.stop_button_pressed = False
        self.worker1 = Worker1()
        self.worker2 = Worker2()
        self.worker1.signals.finished.connect(self.progress)
        self.worker2.signals.finished.connect(self.progress)
        self.threadpool.start(self.worker1)
        self.threadpool.start(self.worker2)

worker 1 and 2 each run the following methods, respectively (simulated serial port I/O, using time.sleep), then emit the "finished" signal:
    # run by worker1
    def get_data_1(self):
        self.index_1 += 1
        time.sleep(0.1)
        return self.index_1

    # run by worker2
    def get_data_2(self):
        self.index_2 += 1
        time.sleep(0.1)
        return self.index_2

Progress function, which is supposed to restart threads when active threadcount is 0:
    def progress(self):
        if self.stop_button_pressed == True:
            print('stop button pressed')
            return
        thread_count = self.threadpool.activeThreadCount()
        print('thread count: ', thread_count, 'indices', self.index_1, self.index_2)
        if thread_count == 0:
            self.start()

The problem is that the threads are not reliably restarted. I think this may be because if both threads finish at about the same time, they both emit finish and run the "progress" method at practically the same time; the call to obtain the thread count is too fast such that thread_count does not have a chance to update to 0.
Here is the printed output to the terminal:
thread count:  1 indices 1 1
thread count:  0 indices 1 1
thread count:  1 indices 2 2
thread count:  0 indices 2 2
thread count:  2 indices 3 3
thread count:  0 indices 3 3
thread count:  1 indices 4 4
thread count:  1 indices 4 4

At this point, threads stopped re-executing since both finished and thread count was 1 twice on the last two iterations.
I tried many different ways to try to accomplish this behavior, but no matter how I try to implement it, it tends to end in threads stopping (because the threads are not being restarted as intended). The expected/intended behavior is for synchronized threads to loop only when both are finished, or until a stop button is clicked.
I tried asking chatGPT, searching stack overflow, and google, and there seems to be no good solution. Sometimes there is mention of the GIL, but I think serial port I/O tasks can benefit from this type of synchronization.
Also tried using a Mutex, with no luck:
    def progress(self):
        if self.stop_button_pressed == True:
            print('stop button pressed')
            return
        self.mutex.lock()
        thread_count = self.threadpool.activeThreadCount()
        print('thread count: ', thread_count, 'indices', self.index_1, self.index_2)
        if thread_count == 0:
            self.start()
        self.mutex.unlock()


You could try to delay the signal, by using something like this when you connect the finished signals: self.worker1.signals.finished.connect(lambda: QTimer.singleShot(0, self.progress())).
